# Why is Steam not able to connect Steam-Network?

Tags: networking, connection, steam

This is the output when I try to start steam. It closes with the Message "Keine Verbindung zum Steam-Netzwerk möglich..." (No connection to Steam-Network...)

Removing appcache didn't help so far.

```
running Steam on ubuntu 13.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
unlinked 0 orphaned pipes
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
[1004/102851:WARNING:proxy_service.cc(646)] PAC support disabled because there is no > system implementation
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
Generating new string page texture 2: 48x256, total string texture memory is 49,15 KB
Generating new string page texture 3: 256x256, total string texture memory is 311,30 KB
(steam:12440): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: g_simple_async_result_complete() called from wrong context!
(steam:12440): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: g_simple_async_result_complete() called from wrong context!
(steam:12440): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: g_simple_async_result_complete() called from wrong context!
(steam:12440): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: g_simple_async_result_complete() called from wrong context!
(steam:12440): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: g_simple_async_result_complete() called from wrong context!
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
`menu_proxy_module_load': /home/ex00r/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam: undefined symbol: menu_proxy_module_load
(steam:12440): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: (null)
(steam:12440): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
(steam:12440): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
(steam:12440): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
(steam:12440): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
(steam:12440): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
(steam:12440): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
(steam:12440): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
(steam:12440): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
(steam:12440): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
(steam:12440): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
(steam:12440): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
roaming config store loaded successfully - 6339 bytes.
migrating temporary roaming config store
Adding license for package 0
Adding license for package 11
Adding license for package 79
Adding license for package 517
Adding license for package 1292
Adding license for package 2243
Adding license for package 2753
Adding license for package 3024
Adding license for package 4314
Adding license for package 4819
Adding license for package 8198
Adding license for package 8892
Adding license for package 11107
Adding license for package 11108
Adding license for package 11262
Adding license for package 13533
Adding license for package 14481
Adding license for package 17982
Adding license for package 32744
Adding license for package 32745
Adding license for package 32747
Generating new string page texture 4: 128x256, total string texture memory is 442,37 KB
Generating new string page texture 5: 384x256, total string texture memory is 835,58 KB
Generating new string page texture 6: 1024x256, total string texture memory is 1,88 MB
Generating new string page texture 7: 512x256, total string texture memory is 2,41 MB
Generating new string page texture 8: 24x256, total string texture memory is 2,43 MB
unlinked 2 orphaned pipes
CAsyncIOManager: 0 threads terminating.  0 reads, 0 writes, 0 deferrals.
CAsyncIOManager: 804 single object sleeps, 0 multi object sleeps
CAsyncIOManager: 0 single object alertable sleeps, 1 multi object alertable sleeps
[2013-10-04 10:28:50] Startup - updater built Jun  6 2013 13:48:29
[2013-10-04 10:28:50] Installation wird überprüft...
[2013-10-04 10:28:50] Verification complete
Shutting down. . .
[2013-10-04 10:29:08] Shutdown
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Removing appcache helped me till a new steam version was released which seems to have it fixed.

You can remove appcache via terminal

```
rm -Rf ~/.steam/steam/appcache
```

Don't do this with sudo.

Answer (score 31):

Same problem on German Ubuntu forum

http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/steam-verbindet-nicht-zum-server/

This command helped me too

```
steam --reset
```

Comment: Answer from user1990879 works for me fine...
One note: don't do it with sudo (some users with this habit will be captured with error "Scannot run as root user"!)
And all will works fine.

Comment: Ahh shit, **this deletes all your installed games.**

Comment: For me, it didn't delete all installed games and it helped to solve a problem of me being always in connecting state

Comment: I can also confirm that my games remained installed, and this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I have been able to reproduce this with perfect network connectivity when steam is closed unexpectedly. The solution in my case was to remove:

`.local/share/Steam/config`

This solution worked for me, and didn't force me to reinstall any game, just to login again

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the steps from this [article](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1456-EUDN-2493)?

Comment: Forwarding Ports in Fritz.Box and connecting directly via LAN didn't work. Also the -tcp option didn't.

Comment: Can you login directly on the Steam-Website: http://www.steampowered.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

I think in my case it was just that the Steam Auth servers were overloaded/down. Not much that can be done about that; I recommend checking Reddit to see if any recent discussion mentions an outage: https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam